# Unexpected Token Exception in SQL Query in @Query() annotation in Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am using a long SQL Query String inside `@Query()` annotation in Spring. I'm getting exceptions for multiple tokens. Can anybody provide the solution for the query below:

```
@Query("select p, top5.duration_seconds / 60 as duration_minutes, top5.max_seconds / 60 as max_minutes " +
            "from (select r.driver_id, "+
         "sum(to_seconds(r.end_time) - to_seconds(r.start_time)) as duration_seconds, "+
         "max(to_seconds(r.end_time) - to_seconds(r.start_time)) as max_seconds "+
         "from ride r "+
         "where r.start_time >= '2018-08-08T12:12:12'  and "+
         "r.end_time <= '2018-08-08T18:12:12' "+
         "group by r.driver_id "+
         "order by duration_seconds desc "+
         "limit 5 "+
         ") top5 join "+
         "person p "+
         "on top5.driver_id = p.id")
```

It shows

> UnExpectedToken: sum
>
> antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: (
>
> antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting EOF, found ')'

Comment: Is your sql query return data from database when you query it? And as I know you can't use functions like `sum()` in query without specify `@Query(sql, native=true)` .

Comment: @EmreSavcı: Hi Yes, I'm getting correct result with this query in MySQL Workbench, if I use * after p in 1st line. Rest query will remain same.

Comment: This is a SQL query, but what `@Query` expects is not a SQL query. It expects a JPQL query. Unless you set its `nativeQuery` attribute to true.